# why can't i offset edges?

Tags: geometry-nodes

i can offset faces like this:

[image]

i can offset points like this:

[image]

why can't i offset edges like this?

[image]

Note: the only difference in the node trees is the domain in the capture attribute node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This phenomenon again has to do with the interpolation of values between domains.

For example, when you select a face or an edge, it always refers to multiple points.

But the node `Set Position` always moves only single points, so these values are evaluated starting from the point domain.

Take as an example:

If you capture the index of an edge in the edge domain with `Capture Attribute`, and interpolate these values to the point domain, you will get float values in it:

[image]

Likewise, if you capture the index in the face domain and interpolate to the point domain. *By the way: It was a coincidence that the faces worked for you. This only came about because it was a matter of faces for which the interpolation led to a reasonably useful result.*

So, in fact, they are never integer values. Only if you explicitly set the data type to *Integer*, the float value is then additionally converted into an integer value. But of course this leads to nonsensical data for such an application.

Consider:

A point can always belong to more than one face or edge, so the selection will fail in this way.

To solve the task, you would first have to perform a comparison, and capture the result as a boolean value.
This can then be used in the point domain without any problems:

[image]

Comment: You can also use the `Interpolate Domain` node in most cases, I think: https://i.imgur.com/0ufn2JX.png

Comment: @Kuboå: That's great!!! Thanks!